# Django - passing named parameter to url in template

Tags: django, templates, url, parameters, get

For some reason I don't understand, when I pass a parameter to my url inside my template, the generated url does not include the parameter keyword "?ts=".

To be clearer, the code below generate as href the url `my_view20230511` instead of `my_view?ts=20230511`. What puzzles me even more is that all urls still work : I mean I can access `my_view`, `my_view20230511` and `my_view?ts=20230511`

`my_view` and `my_view?ts=20230511` have the behaviour I want which is : the page is same for both but for the second I also have the content of some file rendered

But I don't need `my_view20230511` since I would like this line `<a href="{% url 'my_view' ts=ts %}">{{ ts_fmt }}</a>` to point to `my_view?ts=20230511`

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^my_view(?P<ts>\d+)?$', views.my_view, name = "my_view")
    ]
```

**views.py**

```py
def my_view(request, ts=""):
    ts = request.GET.get('ts', "")
    timestamps = [('20230509', datetime(2023,5,9),
                  ('20230510', datetime(2023,5,10),
                  ('20230511', datetime(2023,5,11)]
  
    context = {
        'timestamps' : timestamps,
        'ts' : ts
    }
    
    if ts != "":
        with open(f"filepath/that/depends/on/{ts}", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        context['lines'] = lines

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

**template.html**

```html
{% for ts,ts_fmt in timestamps %}
   <p><a href="{% url 'my_view' ts=ts %}">{{ ts_fmt }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}

{% if msg %}
      {% for line in lines %}
         <p>{{ line }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I can't find any help on this issue so trying my luck on stackoverflow...I hope I made it clear enough to be understood ?

**EDIT**

First error was trying to declare a query parameter in my urls as Charlesthk pointed out. And second was the way of adding the query parameter to the url from the template. Hence a solution (removing the parameter from urls and views and changing syntax in template) is :

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('my_view', views.my_view, name = "my_view")
    ]
```

**views.py**

```py
def my_view(request):
    ts = request.GET.get('ts', "")
    timestamps = [('20230509', datetime(2023,5,9),
                  ('20230510', datetime(2023,5,10),
                  ('20230511', datetime(2023,5,11)]
  
    context = {
        'timestamps' : timestamps,
        'ts' : ts
    }
    
    if ts != "":
        with open(f"filepath/that/depends/on/{ts}", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        context['lines'] = lines

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

**template.html**

```html
{% for ts,ts_fmt in timestamps %}
   <p><a href="{% url 'admin_mail' %}?ts={{ ts }}">{{ ts_fmt }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}

{% if msg %}
      {% for line in lines %}
         <p>{{ line }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django, query parameters should not be declared in your urls :

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('my_view', views.my_view, name="my_view")
]
```

With this declaration, both `/my_view` and `/my_view?foo=bar` resolve to `views.my_view`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Good to know ! It didn't quite resolve the issue since I then had a "Reverse not found" error but I could pass the query parameters using some syntax.I edit my question to present the solution